# How do you re-use Javascript scripts?

Tags: javascript

I've got a calculation script that executes when the page loads, but also when the window gets resized. The code in between is exactly the same; not re-used.

So I was wondering, not if, but how do I re-use Javascript code?

I've tried a few stuff, like the next piece, but that ain't working.

```
$(function reUse() {
    alert('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
    console.log('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    reUse();
});
```

So what should be the correct way of formatting?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should put the function outside of the closure. You are now adding the function as a jQuery object. The way to go would be:

```
var reUse = function() {
    alert('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
    console.log('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
};

$(window).resize(function() {
    reUse();
});
```

And you'll want to wrap it all in a closure:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // the code above
});
```

Comment: I assume that also applies for the actual code; write it as a variable and re-use that in the functions where it's needed? -> http://pastebin.com/MaLYCMc9 - Thanks! - And second! Why 'jQuery(document).ready(function($)' instead of $(document).ready(function() {}); - Which seems shorter?

Comment: yup, looks good! in javascript you can put everything in a variable: a primitive value, object or function. So anything you'd like to use again, put it in a variable!

Answer (score 2):

You're missing a few parenthesis etc, and you can just trigger event handlers

```
$(function() {
    function reUse() {
        alert('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
        console.log('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
    }

    $(window).on('resize', reUse).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: Why "$(window).on('resize', reUse).trigger('resize');" instead of $(window).resize(function() {
    reUse();
});    ? Using .trigger() seems a little overdone, since .resize() is enough?

Comment: @SanderSchaeffer - It's to trigger the function **both** on pageload and on resize

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this

```
function reUse() {
    alert('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
    console.log('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
}

$(window).resize(reUse);
```

Comment: Why would the asker's version fail, though?

Comment: Because of the visibility of the reUse function, please read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/javascript-variable-scope

Answer (score 1):

try to make it global, in your scope:

```
var reUse;
$(reUse = function reUse() {
    alert('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
    console.log('Either the page got resized or the page loaded!');
});

$(window).resize(function() {
    reUse();
});
```

or for the second use, if you don't have any special parameter to pass to your function:

```
$(window).resize(reUse);
```